# Can tikz projections be computed in three dimensions?

Tags: tikz-pgf, calc, tikz-calc

According to the [pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf#page=139), the syntax

```
<coordinate>!<projection coordinate!<angle>:<second coordinate>
```

can be used to project `<projection coordinate>` orthogonally onto the line from
`<coordinate>` to `<second coordinate>`.

I can get this working fine in two dimensions:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  , line join=round
  , line cap=round
  ]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
  \coordinate (v) at (2, 0);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 1);
  \coordinate (p) at ($ (O)!(b)!(v) $);

  \draw[ultra thick, ->, blue] (O) -- (v) node[right] {$\vec{v}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, red] (O) -- (b) node[above] {$\vec{b}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, purple] (O) -- (p) node[below] {$\vec{p}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in three dimensions something goes wrong

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  , line join=round
  , line cap=round
  ]
  \coordinate (O) at (0, 0, 0);
  \coordinate (v) at (0, 0, 1);
  \coordinate (b) at (1, 2, 1);
  \coordinate (p) at ($ (O)!(b)!(v) $);

  \draw[ultra thick, ->, blue] (O) -- (v) node[right] {$\vec{v}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, red] (O) -- (b) node[above] {$\vec{b}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, purple] (O) -- (p) node[below] {$\vec{p}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The projection of `(1, 2, 1)` onto the line spanned by `(0, 0, 1)` is `(0, 0, 1)`, which is clearly incorrect in the figure.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of `tikz`?

Answer (score 4):

The answer is: no, the public libraries do not yet support 3d computations. There is, however, an **experimental** library [3dtools](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools), which you may want to check out. Save [this file](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex) as `tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex` somewhere where LaTeX will find it, e.g. in the same directory in which the MWE below is. This library supports scalar products and much more.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3dtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  , line join=round
  , line cap=round
  ]
  \path (0, 0, 0) coordinate (O) 
   (0, 0, 2) coordinate (v) 
   (1, 2, 1) coordinate (b); 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myproj}{TD("(b)o(v)")/TD("(v)o(v)")}
  \path[3d coordinate={(p)=\myproj*(v)}];

  \draw[ultra thick, ->, blue] (O) -- (v) node[right] {$\vec{v}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, red] (O) -- (b) node[above] {$\vec{b}$};
  \draw[ultra thick, ->, purple] (O) -- (p) node[below] {$\vec{p}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how can I change the old syntax `\path[overlay,3d coordinate={(nBAD)=(B)-(A)x(B)-(D)}]`, to new syntax?

Comment: @minhthien_2016 The old syntax should still work. You are computing a vector product, the question is about a scalar product. The new thing is that you can now mix symbolic and explicit coordinates, see [this manual](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/blob/master/experiments/Marmot/3dtools/3DToolsManual.pdf).

Comment: I use your code at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98348/room-for-minhthien-2016-and-schrodingers-cat.  Now I cannot obtain the result.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Just remove `\tikzset{3d coordinate/.style args={#1=#2}{%
/utils/exec=\tdparse<#2>,%
insert path={(\pgfmathresult) coordinate #1}}}`. This has been redefined to become more elegant. `3d coordinate` is now part of the `3dtools` library (as is the possibility to switch on some view).

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm getting an error:

`ERROR: Undefined control sequence.
\pgfmath@dimen@ ...men@@ #1=0.0pt\relax \pgfmath@ 
l.14 ...acro{\myproj}{TD("(b)o(v)")/TD("(v)o(v)")}`

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick Most likely this means that you have an older LaTeX installation. All of this was only possible after Henri Menke kindly added [this feature](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/git/ci/31165f2f43d419e1a921a1881bf25743592577a7/) to Ti*k*Z, and all further major improvements will again require some additions to `tikz.code.tex` (and perhaps also to `tikzlibrarycalc.code.tex`). **bottom-line**: please update your LaTeX installation and try again (and sorry for the inconvenience).